# R - Turn many time series in 1D format into 3D array, with each time series tagged with two labels

Tags: r

I have a one dimensional csv which contains data of many time series, each time series is tagged with two labels.

After reading the file into R, what key function(s) should I use to quickly turn the data into 3D matrix?

The data are in this format:

```
Date, Price, Stock Ticker, Country
1/1/2012, 98, ABC.US, US
1/2/2012, 100, ABC.US, US
.
.
.
1/1/2012, 36, XYZ.US, US
1/2/2012, 34, XYZ.US, US
.
.
.
.
1/1/2012, 78, MNO.LN, UK
1/2/2012, 75, MNO.LN, UK
.
.
```

I want to turn this table into 3D array with dimensions of date, stock ticker and country:

```
3DTable[Date,Ticker,Country]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that @sebastian-c interpreted your question correctly, this is a one-liner in base R that gets you there:

```
tapply(x$Price, x[, -2], c)
# , , Country = UK
# 
#           Stock.Ticker
# Date       ABC.US MNO.LN XYZ.US
#   1/1/2012     NA     78     NA
#   1/2/2012     NA     75     NA
# 
# , , Country = US
# 
#           Stock.Ticker
# Date       ABC.US MNO.LN XYZ.US
#   1/1/2012     98     NA     36
#   1/2/2012    100     NA     34
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer for what you want.

Create data frame

```
x <- data.frame(Date=rep(c("1/1/2012", "1/2/2012"), 3), 
  Price=c(98, 100, 36, 34, 78, 75),
  "Stock Ticker"=rep(c("ABC.US", "XYZ.US", "MNO.LN"), each=2), 
  Country=rep(c("US", "US", "UK"), each=2))
```

Create set of all possible options

```
all.opts <- expand.grid(Date=levels(x$Date), 
  Stock.Ticker=levels(x$Stock.Ticker), 
  Country=levels(x$Country))
```

Join this with the data (there may be a way in base R, but I don't know it)

```
library(plyr)
x2 <- join(all.opts, x)
```

Make the array

```
x.arr2 <- array(x2$Price, dim=c(2, 3, 2), 
  dimnames=list(levels(x2$Date), levels(x2$Stock.Ticker), levels(x2$Country)))
```

Admire handiwork:

```
x.arr2

#, , UK
#
#         ABC.US MNO.LN XYZ.US
#1/1/2012     NA     78     NA
#1/2/2012     NA     75     NA
#
#, , US
#
#         ABC.US MNO.LN XYZ.US
#1/1/2012     98     NA     36
#1/2/2012    100     NA     34
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(plyr)
daply(x, c("Date", "Stock Ticker", "Country"), function(y) y$Price)
```

The first argument to `daply` is your data frame, the second are the variables you want to use as dimensions (perhaps you need to change the space to a dot, depending on how you read your data), and the third is the function which computes the array value from the daraframe row.